# Economics - plural or singular

Tags: grammar

"The economics of the matter **mean** that your proposal is not feasible."

or

"The economics of the matter **means** that your proposal is not feasible."

Comment: Google Books claims 58 instances of ["the economics **are** complex"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+economics+are+complex%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but only 3 of ["the economics **is** complex"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+economics+is+complex%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). But in closely-related usages such as *"Economics **is** too complex for me"* it's obviously the other way around. Having said that, I personally would definitely use plural ***mean*** in OP's exact context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plural is the correct and more common form in your sentence:

[Economics:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/economics) ( from Collins Dictionary )

> - (used with a sing. verb) The social science that deals with the production, distribution, and consumption of goods and services and with the theory and management of economies or economic systems.
> - (Economics) (functioning as plural) financial aspects: the economics of the project are very doubtful.

Answer (score 3):

Economics -  [Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/economics) describes the word as “noun plural but singular/plural in construction.”

Referring to a social science, it’s singular:

> - Economics is often called “the dismal science.”.

Referring to a set of conditions, it’s plural:

> - The economics of the project make it impossible to proceed.
> - **The economics of the matter mean that your proposal is not feasible.**